# Chemical production using calculus

Tags: calculus

I was given this homework and I am getting stuck really bad I can't seem to get it integrated. Can anyone help me I am trying to integrate by parts but I can't get it.

A certain chemical reaction produces a compound X at the rate of

$$6t \, (\sqrt{t+4})^3 \,\rm{ kg/hour}$$

where $t$ is the time (in hours) from the start of the reaction. How much of the compound is produced during the first four hours of the reaction? Round your answer to the nearest kilogram.

Comment: i am afraid of down votes you are going to get now

Comment: its sqrt((t+4)^3)

Answer (score 1):

I really have no idea why the other answers seem unnecessarily complicated.   This is a very simple function, perform the painless substitution $u = t+4$ and you have

$$\int 6t(\sqrt{t+4})^3\, dt = 6 \int (u-4)u^{3/2}\, du = 6 \int u^{5/2} - 4u^{3/2}\, du = 6(\tfrac27 u^{7/2} - 4\cdot\tfrac25 u^{5/2}) + C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $t+4=z^{2/3}$ Now integrate $$6\int(z^{2/3}-4)z\cdot{2\over 3}z^{-1/3}dz  $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Evaluating
$$
I=\int_0^46t(t+4)^{3/2}dt
$$ with the change of variable $t=u^2-4$ gives $dt=2udu$ and

> $$
> I=12\int_2^{2\sqrt{2}}u^4 (u^2-4)\:du
> $$

which is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since $6t$ is a polynomial in $t$ and we can easily integrate $(t+4)^{3/2}$ as many times as necessary, [tabular integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Tabular_integration_by_parts) looks like a good method. My table:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}6t&+&\frac25(t+4)^{5/2}\\6&-&\frac4{35}(t+4)^{7/2}\end{array}$$
Thus
$$\int_0^46t(t+4)^{3/1}dt=\left[\frac{12}5t(t+4)^{5/2}-\frac{24}{35}(t+4)^{7/2}\right]_0^4=\frac{18432\sqrt2+3072}{35}\approx832.5\text{ kg}$$